# Auto-serial-console and ttyPS0 crashing on Linux boot

Tags: linux, console, embedded-linux

I have a Zedboard-like system that I run embedded Linux on. I connect to it via a serial console where I use minicom on my end.

A week ago an issue started where my auto-serial-console where the process will terminate once Linux finishes loading. It will terminate and respawn about 3 times until it finally stabilizes and allows me access.

I've tried reloading my boot.bin, uenv.txt, devicetree, and uImage. The problem seems to come from my root filesystem but I'm unsure of where. I've tried a fresh install on a different SD card and it does not have the issue so it's not a hardware related issue.

For reference my kernel has bootargs: 
`bootargs=console=ttyPS0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw earlyprintk rootfstype=ext4 rootwait`

And this is the console response from dmesg after it allows access:

```
init: auto-serial-console main process ended, respawning
init: openvt main process ended, respawning
init: auto-serial-console main process (1959) terminated with status 1
init: auto-serial-console main process ended, respawning
```

[or see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMaSS.png).]

If you have any ideas to try I would love to know them.

Comment: Please copy the error messages into your question as text (i.e., ordinary copy and paste). If, for some reason, you can’t do that, then just transcribe them (i.e., *type* them in).

Comment: @Scott I have added the error messages as text into the question, thanks.